# "Blank SQL" error with phppgadmin

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin

Here is my problem: I export a database A_DB using "export" function of Phppgadmin. The dump file A_dump.sql includes both the database structure and data. Then I try to create another blank database B_DB, and import A_dump.sql into it.

Every time I do that, the transaction failed with no error reported:

```
SQL error:

In statement:
```

Is there some logs that I can find in phppgadmin that would allow me to investigate this problem? I have tried searching for an hour, but still not find anything.

Comment: And what's there in the PostgreSQL's logs?

Comment: I don't know about phppgadmin logs. But check your Postgres server logs. If there was an SQL error, you'll find information there (with default settings).

Comment: @vyegorov: I don't have the permission required to view the logs on server though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turns out that the uploaded SQL file size exceed the limit of uploading set on the server. Hence phppgadmin "silently" dropped the uploaded file, which leaded to the "blank" SQL error.

When I split that imported SQL file to smaller files, it works.

Comment: I never thought that phppgadmin behave like that for a common error. It seems I should switch to a command-line interface.